# Disabling hardware acceleration without adding an overdraw

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I need to disable hardware acceleration on one of my views [(because it draws dash lines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843402/android-dashed-line-drawable-potential-ics-bug).

But it appears that doing so adds an overdraw on all the view (while my view has a transparent background, and its dash line only cover some part of it).

Why disabling hardware acceleration cause this overdraw ? Is there any way to have no hardware acceleration without adding this overdraw ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution but it might reply the third question your asked.

Avoid overdraw
Do not draw too many layers on top of each other. Remove any views that are completely obscured by other opaque views on top of it. If you need to draw several layers blended on top of each other, consider merging them into a single layer. A good rule of thumb with current hardware is to not draw more than 2.5 times the number of pixels on screen per frame (transparent pixels in a bitmap count!).

Source : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Actually in my case it's not the issue, since i'm not using hardware acceleration on this view.