# Android Dash/doted line issue?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-background

When I am using **android dotted line** its *working fine in Small screens*, but *not working in Samsung  S3 device  and higher versions*.

**Screenshots**

[image: samsung Device]

And

[image: Small screens]

**drawable/dashline.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line" >

     <stroke
        android:dashWidth="20sp"
        android:dashGap="20sp"
        android:width="2dp"
         android:color="#FF0000" />

     </shape>
```

**XML**

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dash_line" />
```

If someone can help me out in this, any idea is appreciable.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/26296229/185022

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dotted line is actually not dotted when app is running on real Android device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931679/dotted-line-is-actually-not-dotted-when-app-is-running-on-real-android-device)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

set `android:layerType="software"` for your imageView. Check the [docs for android:layerType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3alayerType).

Comment: THANK YOU @Pallavi

Comment: Would have never figured that out, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `sp` to `dp` to:

```
<stroke
    android:dashWidth="20dp"
    android:dashGap="20dp"
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FF0000" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Stroke WIDTH must be smaller than the size HEIGHT.

(Stroke width is the width of the line. Size height is the height of the drawable. When drawn, the line is centered in the drawable. If size height <=stroke width, the line won't show up.)

See code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28867281/3817964

Answer (score 0):

sp uses the scale factor of the device's font setting, rather than just the scale factor of the screen's density (dp) - don't use sp for non-text related dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this following line to your AndroidManifest - application tag

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```