# Dotted line separator with custom thickness

Tags: android, xml, paint, stroke

I have a dotted line separator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <!-- 
#17b851 #C7B299
     -->
    <stroke
       android:color="#9e9c85"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" 
       />
</shape>
```

Right now its barely visible. How can I make it thick . I tried giving            android:height="2px" &        android:dashHeight="5px"
 but it didnt work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use stroke width,

```
android:width="3dp"
```

snapshot

> [image]

Comment: @Justin works fine. if it does not work for you doesn't mean it will not work for others. And why is this downvoted

Comment: @Justin On what basis have you come to the conclusion that this does not work. And where is your code that does not work?? If it does not work it would not have been accepted

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. The dashed line is correctly displayed in layout editor but invisible on the device. It also doesn't help to set the layerType to software, which is a common fix.

Comment: @McLovin does work for me. other than that i don't know much and post what you have done and on what versions did you try

Comment: @McLovin if it does not work you need to be more specific. There is also other solution where you can draw a dotted line on the canvas

Answer (score 12):

Stroke WIDTH must be smaller than the size HEIGHT.

(Stroke width is the width of the line.  Size height is the height of the drawable.  When drawn, the line is centered in the drawable. If size height <=stroke width, the line won't show up.)

dottedline.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="3dp"
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

    <size android:height="3dp" />
</shape>
```

the layout xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:layerType="software"
        android:contentDescription="underline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dottedline" />
```

Comment: Alternatively, (without size height) the layout_height in the ImageView can be set to something larger than the stroke width and it should work too.

Answer (score 2):

use like this it is use full And THIS [DOTTED LINE IN ANDROID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281889/android-adding-dots-line-to-layout/21282044#21282044)

`EDIT :` [Here is Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983788/android-dash-doted-line-issue)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="line" >

   <solid android:color="#fdfdfd" >
   </solid>

 <stroke
  android:dashGap="5px"
  android:dashWidth="5px"
  android:width="2dp"
  android:color="@color/scoreColor" >
</stroke>

</shape>
```

in xml file use this

`NOTE` : Note: With out this line in Higher versions not working android:layerType="software"

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/dash_line"
    android:layerType="software"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Comment: Ading this line android:layerType="software" solves the problem on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a line like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="line">

 <stroke
android:dashGap="3dp"
android:dashWidth="8dp"
android:height="2px"
android:color="#E90C0C" />

</shape>
```

and use it in your view as

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/vDottedLine"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2px"
    android:layerType="software" />
```