# Android L is not able to draw dotted line as drawable background

Tags: xml, shapes, android-5.0-lollipop, dotted-line

Android L is not able to draw dotted line as drawable background as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item> 
<shape  android:shape="line" >

    <stroke
        android:dashGap="1dp"
        android:dashWidth="1dp"
        android:color="#999999" />

    <size android:height="1dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

I am also using layerType='software' in xml.
Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried adding a stroke width?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1.The view must be at least 2dp in height (or `wrap_content`), in order for it to display since a stroke is designed to go around the view and it doesn't have room to do so in 1dp.

2.Add width to your xml:

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:dashGap="1dp"
    android:dashWidth="1dp"
    android:color="#999999" />

<size android:height="1dp" 
    android:width="1dp"/>
```

3.Use `layerType='software'`

Comment: android:width="1dp" in stroke is a must for android 5.0 and higher

Comment: Hey Itai, the `size` declaration in your example is not correct. If the `stroke` in your `shape` has a `width` of `1dp` then its `size` must have a `height` of at least `2dp`. Likewise if the `stroke` in your `shape` has a `dashWidth` of `1dp` then its `size` must have a `width` of at least `3dp`.