# CardView not showing shadow elevation

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I am working with cardviews but the problem is my CardView is not showing any elevation or shadow. I have already tried some of the methods suggested in stackoverflow answers like I have tried using elevation and shadow property. I have also tried using card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true", but without any success. This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FAFBFD"
    app:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/post_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/post_profile_image"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_time"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="@color/grayColor"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
                    android:id="@+id/post_delete_btn"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/add_btn"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:text="Text about Posting...."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/like_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/grey_like_bt"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_like_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="0 Likes"
                android:textColor="#2196F3"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/comment_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/comment_btn_gray"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_comment_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="0 Comments"
                android:textColor="#2196F3"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:id="@+id/post_edit_btn"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Dont know why it is not showing any elevation and shadow

Comment: where is `cardElevation`?

Comment: I have used elevation but it was not giving any results so I have removed it

Comment: margin and shadow elevation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369691/how-to-add-colored-border-on-cardview

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP. I've posted my solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398321/1617737 - to a similar question.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Do not forget that to draw shadow you must use hardwareAccelerated drawing

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

see for details 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html?hl=ru

Answer (score 54):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/item_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_white_1000"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`  is the main catch here

Comment: I know that `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>` may cause some troubles, so `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` is the best solution, I think.

Comment: But when we use app:cardUseCompatPadding="true", we can not control the exact padding we want right ?  That will give default padding

Answer (score 10):

If your manifest file has a `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` line, delete it.

Answer (score 10):

Lot of good answers, but sometimes just one doesn't work for all.
here's the one that worked for me after a lot of looking around,

Add this line to your `CardView`

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

So your cardview looks like this

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/cardView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"/>
```

Hope that works! Happy coding!

Comment: it's work for me.

Answer (score 8):

use this inside cardView to show shadow:

```
app:cardElevation="4dp"
app:cardMaxElevation="4dp"
```

Comment: I have used this Divyesh still not getting elevation in emulator and phone

Comment: add app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: This as well Divyesh I have already pointed out this in the question itself

Answer (score 6):

You forget two things.

- First of all, check your project's `AndroidManifest.xml` file, in the `Application` tag you have to write

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>`

instead of

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>`

1. Then check the parent tag of your layout file is there written like below line.
2. if you wanna use `app:` xmlns. then write :
   `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

   **OR**
   `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

**NOTE:**  You don't need to write both simultaneous. Because it gives you duplicate attribute error.

The above line is most important when you use the attributes of `res-auto`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should have to try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--Put your other fields between this-->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Tried this as well still not getting

Answer (score 3):

There are two things that helped me solve this problem:

1. Setting this in the application tag of my manifest:

   ```
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
   ```
2. File > Invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/driverCurrentJobsCardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dim_8"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="4dp"/>
```

And make sure that you are using this dependency in gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

remove below line from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in CardView widget

```
app:cardElevation="5dp"
```

hope this will help!

Comment: First remove background of cardview then try this

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
    card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Use above code and don't forget to use `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`. 
It will work definitely.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a **parent for the Card View**, *try setting a background color for the parent layout* like a color #EDEDED , anything other than white. This will also make a clear difference between card and the background.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EDEDED"
    >
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardone"        
        android:elevation="10dp"   
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
       >
```

**android:background="#EDEDED" on the parent layout** makes the difference.

And **don't use** `android:elevation="10dp"` , use `app:cardElevation="10dp"`

Comment: instead of `android:elevation="10dp"`  `app:cardElevation="10dp"` gives a better effect

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your rootview:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and use this code for elevation:

```
card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
```

Comment: Well i pasted your xml code and the cardview is showing shadows here. try using ``invalidate cache and restart`` option in android studio maybe that could help !

Answer (score 0):

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffff8800">
     ......
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Remove the background color first, add the elevation and later add the background again. Worked for me, though I had added the background through the layout designer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was using Theme.AppCompat instead of Theme.MaterialComponents in as my AppTheme.

```xml
 <style name="Theme.Main" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

In your layout, use MaterialCardView instead of CardView

```xml
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `android:outlineProvider="bounds"` to the CardView layout.

Answer (score -2):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp" >

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Tried this still not getting elevation