# Elevation has no shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

My tab won't show any shadow underneath, what is wrong with my code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#171717"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/tabBackground"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#425ced"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#425ced"
        app:tabTextColor="#e5e5e5"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of support library are you using? 27.0.0 has just resolved most of elevation problems, older version does not support elevation for al components

Comment: [see your answer here ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407492/7707187) it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
app:elevation="10dp"
```

Instead of

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#171717"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:tabBackground="@color/tabBackground"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#425ced"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#425ced"
        app:tabTextColor="#e5e5e5"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't use

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

use this one

```
app:elevation="10dp"
```

and upgrade your support library to last version to have a better performance. good luck