# android, how to draw dotted line in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, draw, ondraw, dotted-line

I refered to this link: [How do I make a dotted/dashed line in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android), and used `DashPathEffect`. But this does not work for me? why? my code:

```
public class NoteEditText extends EditText {
    private Paint mPaint;

    public NoteEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NoteEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        PathEffect effects = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5,5,5},1);  
        mPaint.setPathEffect(effects);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int height = this.getHeight();
        int lineHeight = this.getLineHeight();
        int lineNum = height / lineHeight;
        L.l("line count: " + lineNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < lineNum; i++) {
            int y = (i + 1) * lineHeight;
            canvas.drawLine(0, y, this.getWidth() - 1, y, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The method setPathEffect is not supported by hardware acceleration. By default it is turned on (I think since Android 4.0)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported

You can turn off hardware acceleration inside the constructor with following code snippet:

> setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Answer (score 1):

```
new float[]{5,5,5,5}
```

try

```
new float[]{5,10,15,20}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

> EditText editText=(EditText) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
>
> editText.setPaintFlags(editText.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use the "for loop" to draw line.set setStrokeWidth($diameter) maybe useful. I have write a simple view supporting this function,detail [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115534/1251276)