# How to draw ColorLine in TeeChart with DASH style?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I'm triyng to add a ColorLine Tool to my TeeChart on Android (Java version).
Everything works fine except I can't make the line to be drawn with DASH style.

Here's my code snippet:

```
ColorLine closeLabelLine = new ColorLine(chart.getChart());
closeLabelLine.setValue(closeValue);
closeLabelLine.setAxis(chart.getAxes().getRight());
closeLabelLine.getPen().setStyle(DashStyle.DASH);  //Seems like no effect!
closeLabelLine.getPen().setColor(CLOSE_LABEL_COLOR);
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE:

After testing Yeray's solution by setting `chart.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` and `closeLabelLine.setDraw3D(false);` everything seemed to be working. But after adding axis breaks tool I've got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore
        at android.graphics.Canvas.native_restore(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.restore(Canvas.java:497)
        at com.steema.teechart.android.Graphics3DAndroid.restore(Graphics3DAndroid.java:356)
        at com.steema.teechart.android.Graphics3DAndroid.unClip(Graphics3DAndroid.java:362)
        at com.steema.teechart.tools.AxisBreaksTool.drawRectangle(AxisBreaksTool.java:410)
        at com.steema.teechart.tools.AxisBreaksTool.doDrawLine(AxisBreaksTool.java:720)
        at com.steema.teechart.tools.AxisBreaksTool.chartEvent(AxisBreaksTool.java:748)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.broadcastToolEvent(Chart.java:1035)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.drawAllSeries(Chart.java:813)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.drawAxesSeries(Chart.java:802)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.internalDraw(Chart.java:782)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.paint(Chart.java:2169)
        at com.steema.teechart.Chart.paint(Chart.java:2185)
        at com.steema.teechart.TChart.onDraw(TChart.java:326)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15114)
        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:14343)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14029)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14008)
        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3388)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3367)
```

I've found `chart.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);` causes the chart to work without exceptions, but ColorLine is displayed solid, not with dashes as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tips that may help you to get the desired result:

- First note [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24467362/509369) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#unsupported). If you want to draw DASH lines, you'll have to disable the Hardware Acceleration from API 11:

  ```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>10)
      chart.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  ```
- Also note the `ColorLine` tool by default draws the sides and the back. To disable this and only draw the front line:

  ```
  closeLabelLine.setDraw3D(false);
  ```

---

UPDATE:

As you say in the updated part of the question, using the fix suggested produces an error when using `AxisBreaksTool`.
Actually, I found there were missing some calls to `canvas.save()` when clipping in some internal functions, producing this and maybe other crashes.
I've added the required calls in the internal sources and it seems to work fine for me here.
However, I can't think on a workaround to make it work in current release so I'm afraid you'll have to wait for the next maintenance release (you can send mail to "info at steema dot com" asking for a test release).

---

UPDATE 2:

I initially modified the TeeChart sources to disable the Hardware Acceleration internally when a pen is set to DASH style. But `setLayerType` was [implemented in API 11](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayerType%28int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) so, to keep TeeChart support from API 7, I had to remove it and let the developer to do this when necessary.

Comment: I've edited my question where added an exception that I've faced. Could you please suggest a workaround?

Comment: thank you, @Yeray! Could you name the planned date of the next maintenance release? Is there any options to subscribe to updates?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you a date for the next maintenance release to be published. In the meanwhile, as I mentioned in the answer, we'll be pleased to send you a test version

Comment: After testing the provided maintenance build I can confirm that ColorLine with DASH style is drawn correctly. Thank you, @Yeray!