# Drawing dashed line on Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, paint

I want to draw horizontal dashed lines between programmatically generated TextViews. I tried this code :

```
Paint fgPaintSel = new Paint();
fgPaintSel.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
fgPaintSel.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
fgPaintSel.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5, 10}, 0));
```

But nothing happened. I just copied and pasted this code. What should I do to draw a dashed line? Thanks.

Comment: try to call canvas.drawPath(mPath, fgPaintSel); method after this

Comment: @NKushwah It can't resolve `canvas` and `mPath`. Thanks.

Comment: post whole code of that class or method.

Comment: @NKushwah I posted whole code. That's all code I have for drawing.

Comment: have you overrided onDraw() ?

Comment: may be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528572/draw-dash-line-on-a-canvas can help you

Comment: @NKushwah I don't know how to use canvas, can you post an example for it?

Comment: if you want to add static dashed line then you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android

Comment: I want to draw line programmatically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a dotted_line.xml file in drawable folder:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:left="-3px"
        android:right="-3px"
        android:top="-3px">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <stroke
                android:width="2px"
                android:color="@color/dark_blue"
                android:dashGap="2px"
                android:dashWidth="3px" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Add this drawable as background:

```
view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dotted_line));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Worked like charm, thanks! There is one problem. When textView is short, line is short too, I want the line to be at full length all the time. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: @jason Possibilities: 1. set a fixed width of the view, 2. setMinimumWidth of the view, 3. set left and right padding of the view, 4. put it inside a layout and add the dotted line to the layout

Comment: One last question : how can I make dots more like dashed? Thanks

Comment: android:dashGap - a bigger number -> bigger space between lines,
dashWidth -> a single line width. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11):

Give the Activity Layout an id. I've used a button for this demonstration with an onclick handler PaintDashedLines().

In the content_main.xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" .../>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="PaintDashedLines"
        android:text="Press Me"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Used a static int to count for purposes of demo, with a separate method to create the drawable, for modularisation.

In your activity:

```
static int tvCount = 0;

public void PaintDashedLines(View v) {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tv.setTextSize(25);
    tv.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
    ll.addView(tv);
    tv.setText("TextView " + tvCount);
    ImageView divider = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ll.getWidth(), 2);
    lp.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
    divider.setLayoutParams(lp);
    divider.setBackground(CreateDashedLined());
    ll.addView(divider);
    tvCount++;
}

public static Drawable CreateDashedLined() {
    ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    Paint fgPaintSel = sd.getPaint();
    fgPaintSel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    fgPaintSel.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    fgPaintSel.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5, 10}, 0));
    return sd;
}
```

[image]

-MyActivity
--int count;
--oncreate
--PaintDashedLines(View v)
--public static Drawable CreateDashedLined()

In the build.gradle (though this is not set in stone)

```
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
```

You do not need to do anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I'm using your code like this : 1. Commented out TextView lines. 2. Pasted whole Java code on top of the Activity class. 3. Call `View v = new View(this);
                    PaintDashedLines(v);` where I want dashed lines. But Dashed lines doesn't appear. Can you tell me what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: When I don't comment TextView lines, I can see TextView and number, but I can't see dashed lines.

Answer (score 1):

create `dashed_line.xml` in drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">

  <stroke
     android:color="#C7B299"
     android:dashWidth="10px"
     android:dashGap="10px"
     android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Programmatically add `View`

```
View v = new View(this);
```

and set its `background`

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashed_line);
```

set `height` and `width` of your `View` according to your need.

Comment: @jason What is the problem? you dint get output or what?

Comment: There was no output.

Comment: I tried this one first because it was simpler, but for some reason it didn't appear. The accepted answer did. The layer-list and item position parts seem to make the difference.