# android adding dots line to layout

Tags: android, shapedrawable

i need to add a line of dots to my layout like this

[image]

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/deals_list_item_bckg"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dealImg"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/deals_list_img" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dealDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sed a ite amkt Lantin dolor latim dk kuitshen sed iditur anet" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dealNewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="1248$"
                android:textColor="@color/deals_list_new_price"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dealOldPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dealNewPrice"
                android:text="2500$"
                android:textColor="@color/deals_list_old_price"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in which way i can do this thing
i also try using a ShapeDrawable but still not understand how it works i need an example to see how it work and how do this in may layout between description textview and prices textviews

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android

there are a few ways to do that, above link would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**Note:** in Higher versions, without `android:layerType` attribute will not work. Now add `android:layerType` attribute with `software` value as below

```
android:layerType="software"
```

For more details see [LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)

Your updated layout should be as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dealImg"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dealDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sed a ite amkt Lantin dolor latim dk kuitshen sed iditur anet" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/dash_line"
            android:layerType="software"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dealNewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:text="1248$"
                android:textColor="@color/scoreColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dealOldPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dealNewPrice"
                android:text="2500$"
                android:textColor="@color/scoreColor"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

dash line is `dash_line.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="line" >

       <solid android:color="#fdfdfd" >
        </solid>

      <stroke
          android:dashGap="5px"
          android:dashWidth="5px"
          android:width="2dp"
          android:color="@color/scoreColor" >
      </stroke>

</shape>
```

Comment: just try  know it's working  fine in all versions please see the note in top of the answer...

Comment: how to used its vertically. vertically its not work.

Answer (score 3):

drawable/dot_repeated.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/dot"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

layout

```
...

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dealDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sed a ite amkt Lantin dolor latim dk kuitshen sed iditur anet" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dot_height"
        android:background="@drawable/dot_repeated"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

...
```

Comment: i've got line full of colour but not dots (

Comment: iCaesar because you probably didn't include spacings in the image itself. The dot.png should contain transparent regions like this http://i40.tinypic.com/345bv5h.png

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy higher than what? Why?

Comment: @DoctororDrive see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy it doesn't tell me anything. It says "useful to render drawing primitives not supported by the hardware accelerated pipeline" how does this affect me it if the drawable is a png?