# android dotted line with targetSdkVersion=17 changes to a line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, dotted-line

I have dotted_line_horizontal.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
    <stroke
        android:dashGap="10px"
        android:dashWidth="10px"
        android:color="#5c5c5c" />

</shape>
```

And I'm using this as a background:

```
   <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted_line_horizontal" />
```

When I set android:targetSdkVersion="8" everything is fine, I can see dotted line. When I change to android:targetSdkVersion="17" my dotted line becomes a line. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<solid>` tag, as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15492685/544198).

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
```

This will ensure that the dash part isn't the same color as the empty part.

Comment: It didn't help. Still the same line.