# Dotted line XML in Android

Tags: android, line, dotted-line

I am working on an Android application in which I want to use dotted line XML as a divider in my layout. For this I have used different drawables for this but instead to make a dashed dotted line, it is making a line.

My drawable is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:color="#FF404040"
        android:width="1dp"
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="1dp"
    />
    <size
        android:height="3dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a dotted/dashed line in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Dashed lines are not supported in GL mode.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29944) So Add

```
android:layerType="software"
```

for e.g.

```
<ImageView
    android:layerType="software" // add here
 ...
```

in your xml layout for view or programmatically as

```
view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Or Turn off hardware -acceleration like this:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please tell me where i can put layerType, can you please show it in my code snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
use Below code

<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90" >

    <shape android:shape="line" >

        <stroke

            android:width="1dp"
            android:dashGap="6px"
            android:dashWidth="6px"
            android:color="#C7B299" />
    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Answer (score 1):

may be this help you..

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

    <stroke
       android:color="#C7B299"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" />
</shape>
```

just refer this ..
[How do I make a dotted/dashed line in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="line">
        <stroke
            android:color="#FF404040"
            android:width="5dp"
            android:dashGap="10dp"
            android:dashWidth="10dp"
            />

    </shape>
```