# How to set Material design style to disabled EditText (android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, material-design

I'm trying to make my disabled EditText's style like in guidelines:

[image]
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-labels

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/account_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test_account"
        android:enabled="false" />
```

I've already implemented material design styles, so all my widgets look material.

The question is: **Is there any way to get this dotted underline *using styles*, without putting additional views?**

My `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.Main" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">         
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/android:Widget.Material.EditText</item>
</style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8202451/2826147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up with a custom view. It might be not the most elegant solution but it solves my task.

Hope it will be helpful for someone.

---

**DisabledTextField.java**:

```
package com.kabunov.example.ui.common;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.kabunov.example.R;

public final class DisabledTextField extends FrameLayout {

    private TextView tvCaption;
    private TextView tvText;
    private View divider;

    public DisabledTextField(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DisabledTextField(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DisabledTextField(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.component_disabled_text_field, this);

        tvCaption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption);
        tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);

        final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DisabledTextField);
        if (null != typedArray) {
            final String captionText = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.DisabledTextField_caption);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(captionText)) {
                tvCaption.setVisibility(GONE);
            } else {
                tvCaption.setText(captionText);
                tvCaption.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }

            final String text = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.DisabledTextField_disabledText);
            tvText.setText(text);

            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }

    public final void setCaption(final CharSequence caption) {
        this.tvCaption.setText(caption);
        this.tvCaption.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
    public final void setDisabledText(final CharSequence value) {
        this.tvText.setText(value);
    }
}
```

**/layout/component_disabled_text.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/DisabledTextFieldCaption"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/DisabledTextFieldValue"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/disabled_text_field_background"
        android:layerType="software"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**/values/attributes_disabled_text_field.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DisabledTextField">
        <attr name="caption" format="string"/>
        <attr name="disabledText" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**/drawable/disabled_text_field_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="-1dp"
        android:left="-1dp"
        android:right="-1dp"
        android:top="0dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/text_color_disabled_text_view"
                android:dashGap="2dp"
                android:dashWidth="1dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**/values/styles.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="text_color_disabled_text_view">#61000000</color>

    <style name="DisabledTextFieldCaption">

        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_disabled_text_view</item>

    </style>

    <style name="DisabledTextFieldValue">

        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_disabled_text_view</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

**Example of usage**:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.kabunov.example.ui.common.DisabledTextField
            android:id="@+id/example"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            custom:caption="Some caption"
            custom:disabledText="Disabled text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**And the result**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to do as you've shown, It looks like
[image: sample]

Create `dotted.xml` inside `drawable` folder and paste these

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />    
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#030310"
                android:dashGap="5dp"
                android:dashWidth="5dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then simply set the `android:background` attribute to `dotted.xml` we just created. Your `EditText` looks like this.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/account_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test account"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted"
    style="@style/Theme.Main" <!--Its your custom style-->
    android:enabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no "stock" way. Take the material design guidelines as it is, a guideline ;)