# Changing EditText Underline when disabled

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say I have a edittext input for date of birth:

[image: dob_enabled]

I want to dynamically change its state to then be disabled, and for it to have a dotted underline to show that it's disabled:

[image: dob_disabled]

How would I go about doing that? It would be according to the [google material design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-states):

[image: material_guidelines]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219281/how-to-set-material-design-style-to-disabled-edittext-android can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Material design style to disabled EditText (android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219281/how-to-set-material-design-style-to-disabled-edittext-android)

Comment: well found, but I can't believe there isn't a simpler way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a drawable `underline.xml` in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:dashGap="3.0dp"
        android:dashWidth="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and then programatically apply this drawable and set it as disabled

```
editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_edittext);
editText.setEnabled(false);
editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.underline);
```

Output :

[image]