# How to draw a thick dash line using xml?

Tags: android

I've tried a few answers specified here,  [How do I make a dotted/dashed line in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android)

but the lines are all thin.

What I need is something that is something 10 times thicker. Thanks for reading

**Code result from correct answer:**

*activity_main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.tester.MainActivity">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dotted"
    android:layerType="software"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*dotted.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="line" >
  <stroke
    android:dashGap="10px"
    android:dashWidth="10px"
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="@android:color/black"
    />
</shape>
```

[image: Thick dotted line]

Comment: Such a silly question !

Comment: @Piyush, Care to elaborate on the 'silly' part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In below xml you can change the width according to your need.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="line">

        <stroke
            android:color="#C7B299"
            android:dashWidth="10px"
            android:dashGap="10px"
            android:width="10dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Comment: Does this helps you ? @Short Answer

Comment: What shape did you define? Can you post the complete xml?