# Adding horizontal and vertical dotted lines in android

Tags: android, listview, dotted-line

Please give me code adding vertical dotted lines in a list view.I have tried using creating an xml using shape tag method

Comment: People will help you if you request **help** not `Code`. Post whatever you tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using below code.

**horizontal_dashed_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"
        android:dashWidth="4dp"
        android:dashGap="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

**vertical_dashed_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:drawable="@drawable/horizontal_dashed_line"/>
```

**Usage:**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="4dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_dashed_line"/>
```

Checkout below article for more details.

[How to create vertical or horizontal dashed lines with Android drawables](https://randomnerdfacts.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/vertical-horizontal-dashed-lines-android-drawable/)

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

> InCase the above *verticle.xml* not worked TRY this one. AS this Worked for me.

**vertical_dashed_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:left="-600dp"
    android:right="-600dp">
    <rotate
      android:drawable="@drawable/horizontal_dashed_line"
      android:fromDegrees="90"
      android:visible="true" />
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: in case dotted not visible to your phone use 
`android:layerType="software"` in **<View** tag