# How do I make a dotted/dashed line in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I'd need to replicate android XML view from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202451/3585796) but in Jetpack Compose with pure kotlin

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can simply use a `Canvas` with the method `drawLine` applying as `pathEffect` a [**`PathEffect.dashPathEffect`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/PathEffect.Companion?hl=fa#dashPathEffect(kotlin.FloatArray,kotlin.Float)):

```
    val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
    Canvas(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(1.dp)) {

        drawLine(
            color = Color.Red,
            start = Offset(0f, 0f),
            end = Offset(size.width, 0f),
            pathEffect = pathEffect
        )
    }
```

[image]

You can also apply the same pathEffect to other method as:

```
    val stroke = Stroke(width = 2f,
      pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
    )
    Canvas(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(70.dp)){
       drawRoundRect(color = Color.Red,style = stroke)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: how about the dot effect :/

Comment: val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 10f), 0f)
  drawLine(
            color = Color.Gray,
            start = Offset(0f, 0f),
            end = Offset(0f, size.height),
            pathEffect = pathEffect
        )
in case anyone looking for a vertical line using canvas function

Answer (score 33):

You can create a shape in Jetpack Compose like this:

```
private data class DottedShape(
    val step: Dp,
) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ) = Outline.Generic(Path().apply {
        val stepPx = with(density) { step.toPx() }
        val stepsCount = (size.width / stepPx).roundToInt()
        val actualStep = size.width / stepsCount
        val dotSize = Size(width = actualStep / 2, height = size.height)
        for (i in 0 until stepsCount) {
            addRect(
                Rect(
                    offset = Offset(x = i * actualStep, y = 0f),
                    size = dotSize
                )
            )
        }
        close()
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .height(1.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(Color.Gray, shape = DottedShape(step = 10.dp))
)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: but its not dot effect :/

Comment: @AminKeshavarzian just redefine dotSize with `Size(width = size.height, height = size.height)` and use rounded rect instead of a plain one

Comment: Philpp I have voted your answer back then, could you add now a solution below for a vertical line?

Comment: @F.Mysir just swap all the uses of width with height and x with y

Comment: Can u make this like a circle shape?

Comment: @EddyYoelFresnoHernández I think it's possible with `addArc`, but unlike addRect it's just a stroke, so you'd have to add two arcs with different corner radius plus two lines to create a single segment. If you just need to draw it, Gabriele's way should be easier in these circumstances - just make sure the canvas has the same width/height and pass `width/2` to `drawRoundRect.cornerRadius`. But if you want your content to be visible thorough, that's the way

Comment: I already tried but it was very complicated. I was hoping for some one to get already the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

To create a dotted line in compose, you need to set the line's `cap` to `StrokeCap.Round` and set the dash width (first value in the `intervals` array) to `0f`.

Take note that setting the dash width to `0f` while leaving the line's `cap` set to the default, which is `StrokeCap.Butt`, will make the line invisible.

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
private fun DottedLinePreview() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        drawLine(
            color = Color.Black,
            start = Offset(10.dp.toPx(), 100.dp.toPx()),
            end = Offset(190.dp.toPx(), 100.dp.toPx()),
            strokeWidth = 5.dp.toPx(),
            cap = StrokeCap.Round, // important!
            pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
                intervals = floatArrayOf(
                    0f, // important!
                    8.dp.toPx(), // must be greater than stroke width
                ),
            ),
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Dotted line preview]

Answer (score 0):

Use the below composable wherever you want to put a dashed divider. I just made this function from [Gabriele Mariotti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789273/15707830)

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.PathEffect
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

@Preview
@Composable
private fun DashedDividerPreview() {
    DashedDivider(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
    )
}

@Composable
fun DashedDivider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dashWidth: Dp = 4.dp,
    dashHeight: Dp = 2.dp,
    gapWidth: Dp = 2.dp,
    color: Color = Color.Gray,
) {
    Canvas(modifier) {

        val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(
            intervals = floatArrayOf(dashWidth.toPx(), gapWidth.toPx()),
            phase = 0f
        )

        drawLine(
            color = color,
            start = Offset(0f, 0f),
            end = Offset(size.width, 0f),
            pathEffect = pathEffect,
            strokeWidth = dashHeight.toPx()
        )
    }
}
```