# How to draw circle shape border stroke drawn with separated lines?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to achieve this custom shape with Compose

[image: Receipt image]

But for some reason the separator offseted circle is drawn with a dotted line and here is the code

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ReceiptSeparator () {

    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 8.dp) ,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically  ,) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredSize(50.dp)
                .background(Color.White)
                .offset(-40.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Gray))

        ){}

        Box(
            Modifier
                .height(1.dp)
                .requiredWidth(250.dp)
                .weight(3f)
                .background(Color.Gray, shape = DottedShape(step = 20.dp))
        ){}
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier

                .offset(40.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Gray))
                .background(Color.White)
                .size(50.dp)
        ){}
    }
}
```

Why the circle is drawn with a dotted line and how to achieve this shape correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your circle is not drawn correctly, because `Modifier.border` draws a rectangle border by default, and then you clip it with your `Modifier.clip`. Instead, if you need to apply shape to the border, you need to pass the shape into `Modifier.border`, like this:

```
.border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Gray), shape = CircleShape)
```

But this won't solve your problem. To draw the shadow correctly like shown in your image, you need to apply a custom Shape to your container.

You can use [`Modifier.onGloballyPositioned`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary?hl=PL&skip_cache=true#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).onGloballyPositioned(kotlin.Function1)) to get position of your cutoffs:

```
var separatorOffsetY by remember { mutableStateOf<Float?>(null) }
val cornerRadius = 20.dp
Card(
    shape = RoundedCutoutShape(separatorOffsetY, cornerRadius),
    backgroundColor = Color.White,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
) {
    Column {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp))
        Box(
            Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = cornerRadius)
                .height(1.dp)
                .requiredWidth(250.dp)
                // DottedShape is taken from this answer:
                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789205/3585796
                .background(Color.Gray, shape = DottedShape(step = 20.dp))
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    separatorOffsetY = it.boundsInParent().center.y
                }
        )
        Box(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
    }
}
```

Using this information you can create a shape like following:

```
class RoundedCutoutShape(
    private val offsetY: Float?,
    private val cornerRadiusDp: Dp,
) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ) = Outline.Generic(run path@{
        val cornerRadius = with(density) { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }
        val rect = Rect(Offset.Zero, size)
        val mainPath = Path().apply {
            addRoundRect(RoundRect(rect, CornerRadius(cornerRadius)))
        }
        if (offsetY == null) return@path mainPath
        val cutoutPath = Path().apply {
            val circleSize = Size(cornerRadius, cornerRadius) * 2f
            val visiblePart = 0.25f
            val leftOval = Rect(
                offset = Offset(
                    x = 0 - circleSize.width * (1 - visiblePart),
                    y = offsetY - circleSize.height / 2
                ),
                size = circleSize
            )
            val rightOval = Rect(
                offset = Offset(
                    x = rect.width - circleSize.width * visiblePart,
                    y = offsetY - circleSize.height / 2
                ),
                size = circleSize
            )
            addOval(leftOval)
            addOval(rightOval)
        }
        return@path Path().apply {
            op(mainPath, cutoutPath, PathOperation.Difference)
        }
    })
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of:

```
shape = DottedShape(step = 20.dp)
```