# why Jetpack Compose dashPathEffect not working on the Huawei android 8.1

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I used the jetpack compose dashPathEffect but it's not working on the Huawei device and android 8.1 but it's working fine on the real device and emulator android version 12.
how can i fix it?

```
val pathEffect = PathEffect.dashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10f, 5f), 0f)
    Canvas(
        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        drawLine(
            color = AppColor.brandColor.BLUE_DE_FRANCE,
            strokeWidth = 8f,
            start = Offset(20f, 0f),
            end = Offset(size.width - 20, 0f),
            pathEffect = pathEffect
        )
    }
```

**This is the result of android 8.1**

[image]

Comment: [report it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) to google issue tracker. Meanwhile you can draw  dashes manually as showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789205/3585796) - same idea used inside the shape should work.

Comment: Did you end up reporting the issue? I am having the same problem, the dash effect doesn't work in some devices.

Comment: @JulioE.RodríguezCabañas I used this link rather than PathEffect. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789205/3585796